# tkz-graph : inconsistency between edge and loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tkz-collection

I'm discovering the great package `tkz-graph` and I am experiencing some trouble with the `\Loop` macro.

There seem to be some inconsistencies between the `\Loop` macro and the `\Edge` macro.
For example, in the following document, the labels of the edges are not placed in the same way.
First, the loop has an array  but the edge does not.
Second, the syntax `\( \)` for math-mode works only in the case of the loop.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \Vertex{A}
  \Vertex[x=2,y=0]{B}
  \Loop[dist=1.5cm,dir=WE,label=\(x\)](A)
  \Edges[label=$y$](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Third, the macro `\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = …}`doesn't work for loops and I did not find a solution in the user manual. For example, `\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style ={->}}` doesn't use the same arrow tip for the edge and for the loop.

Finally, the use of `style={->}` produces different results in the loop than in the edge (the path is thicker in the latter). Here is the output from the code above, but with `\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style ={->}}`:
[image: Edge and loop have different styles]

Comment: I get a `./file.tex:8:Bad math environment delimiter. \Loop[dist=1.5cm,dir=WE,label=\(x\)](A)`. So the `\(x\)` doesn't work for the loop for me either. Furthermore, if I set the `EdgeStyle` it also applies to the loop for me. Which version of `tkz-berge` are you using?

Comment: The MWE works with me... (Win7, MikTeX 2.9, tkz-berge updated today)

Comment: @wh1t3 I use the 2011/06/01 1.00 version of tkz-berge. Note that you need to use the fixltx2e package in order to `\(x\)` works in the loop.

Comment: Apparently I had an outdated version of `fixltx2e`. After using that, it appeats that `\(x\)` is indeed working. In the `Edge` it complains about a missing argument though. For some reason it appears that it is expecting an argument after `\)`. Putting `{}` after it confirms this by fixing the error and resulting in output as we would expect. As far as the `EdgeStyle` goes, I presume the `Loop` defines it's own arrow tip, since it already has one by default. The `EdgeStyle` is loaded first and is then replaced. If you use ,for instance, `dashed` as the `EdgeStyle` it does operate on the loop.

Comment: @Matsaya I agree with about some inconsistency between the `loop` macro and the `edge` macro : with edge `style` is before `EdgeStyle` and with with `Loop` it's `EdgeStyle` the first option. Sorry for this bug because the  behavior is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the french documentation but with the next version I will try to write a english version. The question is about `tkz-graph`and not `tkz-berge`and `tkz-berge`has an english doc !!

A last detail before my answer, I'm not happy about the options(styles) of these packages because I wrote them with xkeyval and it's difficult to get the same options than Tikz. I will write the next version with pgfkeys.

Now the problem appears because there are a lot of method to change the styles. `EdgeStyle`is used to modify a global style for edges, `LoopStyle` is a global style for loops and style is local; `Loop` first looks at `EdgeStyle`, then at `LoopStyle` and at the end applies a local style if this style exists. For the labels, you have `LabelStyle` and then `labelstyle`

The code is

```
\def\tkzGR@loop[#1](#2){%
\setkeys[GR]{loop}{#1}%
\protected@edef\@tempa{%
\noexpand \draw[\cmdGR@loop@color] (#2)%
  edge [EdgeStyle,LoopStyle,\cmdGR@loop@style]%
  node [LabelStyle,\cmdGR@loop@labelstyle]%
  {\cmdGR@loop@label} (#2)}\@tempa;%
}%
```

A possible solution is

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\tikzset{LabelStyle/.style= {fill=yellow}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \Vertex{A}
  \Vertex[x=2,y=0]{B}     
  \Loop[dist=1.5cm,dir=WE,label=\(x\),
        labelstyle={left=12pt,color=red,fill=white,draw}](A)
  \Edges[label=$y$](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
I agree if you find the styles unclear or confused but I will make something better with `pgfkeys`in the next version. I need to make the versions compatible because `tkz-graph` is used by  lot of people.

The first solution of Count Zero is fine too

**Update :** Another solution is to define a personal style and to use only `Tikz`to draw the loops. It's always possible to use tikz.

Comment: Maybe I can help with the translation?

Comment: yes your help  is welcome because my english language is poor!!

Comment: Thank you for the precise explanation, and for the future changes in tkz-graph ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. either you put a white (or other color, but not transparent) background to your node:

   ```
   \documentclass{minimal}
   \usepackage{fixltx2e}
   \usepackage{tkz-berge}

   \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style= {fill=white}}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
     \Vertex{A}
     \Vertex[x=2,y=0]{B}
     \Loop[dist=1.5cm,dir=WE,label=\(x\)](A)
     \Edges[label=$y$](A,B)
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. or you displace the label (this is probably a less elegant hack):

   ```
   \documentclass{minimal}
   \usepackage{fixltx2e}
   \usepackage{tkz-berge}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
     \Vertex{A}
     \Vertex[x=2,y=0]{B}
     \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style= {xshift=-.25cm}}
     \Loop[dist=1.5cm,dir=WE,label=\(x\)](A)
     \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style= {xshift=0cm}}% set shift back to original (0) value
     \Edges[label=$y$](A,B)
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

whichever you prefer. :) Note that in both cases I fumbled with `LabelStyle/.style=...` *not* `EdgeStyle`.

**EDIT:** `EdgeStyle` takes a `labelstyle` parameter, which is basically the same as modifying directy the `LabelStyle`. Therefore I doubt there is another workaround.

**PS:** Too bad the documentation is only in French... I'm saying this because the `tkz` package family is **asolutely terrific** and in fact this language barrier prevents lots of people from using them.

Comment: I have thought about the withe background, but I think it's more a hack than an elegant way do do it. But maybe it's not possible to do better.

Comment: P.S. For me I don't complain for the documentation as I understand french better than english ;), but I see your point.

Comment: @Matsaya: moin non plus, ça ne me dérange pas :)