# Typesetting a directed, weighted graph with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I just started doing things with TikZ today and I run into a problem: there is just no example code snippets for typesetting directed, weighted graphs. Can anyone supply one simple example in an answer?

Comment: By the way, is there anything like that on [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/)?

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/prims-algorithm/ and http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/state-machine/. The first one is not directed but can easily be made so. The second is a state machine, but replacing the edge labels should be straightforward and you obtain a directed weighted graph. And then there is: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tkz-berge/ but I don't know the status of `tkz-berge`. Have a look at the rest of the site as well, many great examples.

Comment: I couldn't seem to find anything on `tkz-berge`. Perhaps it's been retired. Is Altermundus about?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, you could something like that in R, and include the graphic either via a pdf, or automatically via Sweave.

Comment: Ah! Speak of the devil!

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt no `tkz-berge`is  part of TeXLive 2011 but to draw simple graph, you need only `tkz-graph` `texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-graph/tkz-graph.sty`.

Comment: `tkz-berge` appears to be part of the standard distribution now.

Comment: @Altermundus: Oops, sorry, commented at the same time. Good to know! I like this package. :)

Comment: Since it's not strictly an answer to the question I'll just add a comment; I would recommend using a graph layout program such as graphviz (http://www.graphviz.org/) and then an interface such as dot2tex (http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I made `tkz-graph` and `tkz-berge` to help beginners to draw some graphs. `tkz-berge` is used for specials graphs (named graphs in graph theory)

You can use only `tikz` to draw graphs.
**Version with tkz-graph**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\SetVertexNormal[Shape      = circle,
                 FillColor  = orange,
                 LineWidth  = 2pt]
\SetUpEdge[lw         = 1.5pt,
           color      = black,
           labelcolor = white,
           labeltext  = red,
           labelstyle = {sloped,draw,text=blue}]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \Vertex[x=0 ,y=0]{K}
   \Vertex[x=0 ,y=2]{F}
   \Vertex[x=-1,y=4]{D}
   \Vertex[x=3 ,y=7]{H}
   \Vertex[x=8 ,y=5]{B}
   \Vertex[x=9 ,y=2]{N}
   \Vertex[x=5 ,y=0]{M}
   \Vertex[x=3 ,y=1]{S}
   \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {bend left}}
   \Edge[label = $120$](K)(F)
   \Edge[label = $650$](H)(S)
   \Edge[label = $780$](H)(M)
   \Edge[label = $490$](D)(B)
   \Edge[label = $600$](D)(M)
   \Edge[label = $580$](B)(M)
   \Edge[label = $600$](H)(N)
   \Edge[label = $490$](F)(H)
   \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {bend right}}
   \Edge[label = $630$](S)(B)
   \Edge[label = $210$](S)(N)
   \Edge[label = $230$](S)(M)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With arrows on edges

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \SetUpEdge[lw         = 1.5pt,
            color      = orange,
            labelcolor = white]
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal] 
  \SetGraphUnit{3}
  \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append  style={fill}}
  \Vertex{P}
  \NOEA(P){B}  \SOEA(P){M} \NOEA(B){D}
  \SOEA(B){C}  \SOEA(C){L}
  \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}}
  \Edge[label=$3$](C)(B)
  \Edge[label=$10$](D)(B)
  \Edge[label=$10$](L)(M)
  \Edge[label=$10$](B)(P)
  \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={<->}}
  \Edge[label=$4$](P)(M)
  \Edge[label=$9$](C)(M)
  \Edge[label=$4$](C)(L)
  \Edge[label=$5$](C)(D)
  \Edge[label=$10$](B)(M)
  \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={<->,relative=false,in=0,out=60}}
  \Edge[label=$11$](L)(D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**update : Version with `tikz` and `automata`**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,on grid,initial/.style    ={}]
  \node[state]          (P)                        {$P$};
  \node[state]          (B) [above right =of P]    {$B$};
  \node[state]          (M) [below right =of P]    {$M$};
  \node[state]          (D) [above right =of B]    {$D$};
  \node[state]          (C) [below right =of B]    {$C$};
  \node[state]          (L) [below right =of C]    {$L$};
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={->,double=orange}} 
\tikzset{every node/.style={fill=white}} 
\path (C)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$3$} (B)
      (D)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$10$} (B) 
      (L)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$10$} (M)
      (B)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$10$} (P);
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={<->,double=orange}}   
\path (P)     edge [mystyle]   node   {$4$} (M)
      (C)     edge [mystyle]   node   {$9$} (M) 
      (C)     edge [mystyle]   node   {$4$} (D)
      (B)     edge [mystyle]   node   {$5$} (M);
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={<->,relative=false,in=0,out=60,double=orange}}
\path (L)     edge [mystyle]   node   {$10$} (D); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It might be nice to include where these packages can be found (link) and on a personal note, is there any documentation in English? My French is not what it used to be in high school and even then it was pretty bad. Also, it may be better to add a directed example here, since the question specifically asks for it.

Comment: TeXlive 2011, MikTeX or here http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-graph. With the next version, there will be a French version. Count Zero will help me to translate ( http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35738/tkz-graph-inconsistency-between-edge-and-loop ). You have some examples on my site http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/graph/index.html

Comment: That's almost what I need and I have typeset a similar undirected weighted graph using "Prim's algorithm" example from texample.net. Although, I need to include somehow a direction for each edge in the graph. Frankly, the edges should be arrows pointing from a source vertex to a destination vertex rather than simply connecting the two.

Comment: I added an example with arrows on edges. You need to study tikz to modify sometimes the style of edges or vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Altermundus, but I cannot accept your answer as I have a lot of code purely in TikZ/PGF, and, thus, cannot afford porting to tkz-graph. Frankly, I ended up using 'automata' - TikZ-library in order to draw directed, weighted graphs (one, e.g., represented by the second image in your answer).

Comment: @user1049393 Yes I understand your point of view. I added a version of my last code written only with `tikz` and `automata`.

Comment: Is the bent edges graph a joke?

Answer (score 8):

Since I just wanted something easy, here is a stripped down version using `tkz-graph` of Alain Matthes's code that provides reasonable looking math/CS paper defaults and demonstrates some common vertex, edge, and label options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{K}  % standard vertex at (0,0) with Name k
  \Vertex[x=0,y=2]{F}
  \Vertex[x=-1,y=4]{D}
  \Vertex[x=8,y=5]{B}
  \Vertex[x=9,y=2,L=$n$]{N} % custom label
  \Vertex[x=5,y=0,LabelOut,Lpos=-90,Ldist=.2cm]{M} % custom label position
  \Vertex[x=3,y=3.5,NoLabel]{S}  % unlabeled 
  \tikzstyle{LabelStyle}=[sloped]  % rotate labels to match edges
  \Edge[label=$120$,labelstyle={pos=0.3,above}](K)(F)  % custom label position
  \Edge[label=$490$](D)(B)
  \Edge[label=$580$](B)(M)
  \Loop[dir=NO,dist=2cm,label=b,labelstyle={auto}](B) % loop/self-edge
  \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[pre, bend right] % set curved arrow style
  \Edge[label=$210$](S)(N)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample graph]

Useful resources:

- Loops: [How do you make a tkz graph with edges starting and ending at the same vertex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127299/116513)
- Invisible vertices: [Invisible vertices with tkz-graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/invisible-vertices-with-tkz-graph)
- Vertex with no circle: [How do I draw a graph in tikz where the vertices are only represented by the label names?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113322/how-do-i-draw-a-graph-in-tikz-where-the-vertices-are-only-represented-by-the-lab)
- [Referencing a Vertex that has Math Typesetting inside it to make an Edge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95800/referencing-a-vertex-that-has-math-typesetting-inside-it-to-make-an-edge)
- Fine-tuning labels with `labelstyle` (`above`, `sloped`, `pos`, ...) [Labeling Edges in a Weighted Digraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127534/labeling-edges-in-a-weighted-digraph)
- [Change bend angle and swap node position on arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57925/change-bend-angle-and-swap-node-position-on-arrow)

tkz-graph's manual is in French but it contains enough English words or cognates to be decipherable. https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-graph

tkz-graph also comes with useful built-in graph styles:

[image]
[image]