# Dependency graph with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I would like to make a TikZ diagram to show the detailed 
dependency structure of the theorems in my thesis with nodes
and subnodes. Ex:

```
Theorem 4               (A)
   coding theorem       (A1)
       proof techniques (A1a) 
   converse             (A2)

Theorem 5               (B)
```

and then indicate that there is a dependency

```
(A1a) --> (B)
```

which is more precise than saying that
Theorem 5 depends on Theorem 4. More
specifically, this is what I am trying to draw:

[image]

Is there a TikZ package for that?
Or for drawing .deb dependency graphs?

I found one package/framework for course prerequisites:
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/prerequisite-chart/
but the underlying format is very low level
so you are meant to edit with a program.

All advice / example / recommendations will be much appreciated!

Comment: I think [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37185/typesetting-a-directed-weighted-graph-with-tikz) is pretty close. You can also search for keywords graph etc. by using the `[tikz-pgf] graph`. That would search the graph in only TikZ tagged questions.

Answer (score 4):

At http://latex-community.org/know-how/427-stemma-tikz last Thursday an interesting document was just translated from French to English.  It is for manuscript analysis showing relationships between different manuscripts, authors, and texts.  It is in the form a tutorial and I think this may be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used the tikz-dependency package but the first couple of pages looks like this would be a possible answer: http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz-dependency.

Dependency graphs are used heavily by linguists and they create diagrams like what you are showing.  After you build one I recommend you submit it to
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/  where there are lots of inspiring examples and supporting code.