# How to draw graphs in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw simple graph (for example [Petersen Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph)) in LaTeX.

I am using Kile in Ubuntu.

Comment: A good tutorial : [Create Trees and Figures in Graph Theory
with PSTricks](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/joshi/joshi.pdf).

Comment: »[pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)« is very popular for doing such things.

Comment: Check http://www.texample.net/ for possible examples of Petersen or similar graphs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typesetting a directed, weighted graph with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37185/typesetting-a-directed-weighted-graph-with-tikz)

Comment: I think the question is not enough accurate. There are a lot of different graphs. The  link through Petersen's graph seems to specify named graphs or perhaps classic graphs but it's not sure !

Comment: Two links if you like the graphs 1) http://graphtheoryinlatex.wordpress.com/  Rafael uses tkz-graph and 2) http://rvfblog.wordpress.com/  see Graph theory with Sage I think Sage uses tkz-graph and tkz-berge too  (see here about sage and graphs http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/graphs/graph_latex.html )

Comment: If you use other programs to generate your graphs (e.g. [Veusz](http://home.gna.org/veusz/)), you can also easily convert the svg output into an editable LaTeX graph, as there's an extension for Inkscape to save as tikz. 

Yetish Joshi wrote a guest post on our blog explaining the steps to do this -- if this is what you were thinking with your question then you can find more info [here](https://www.writelatex.com/blog/25-beautiful-graphs-how-to-turn-an-inkscape-drawing-into-an-editable-latex-document). Hope this helps (this didn't feel like a full answer so I posted it as a comment).

Comment: I like to use [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) for drawing all sort of stuff. For graphs the easiest way is to use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org), but it isn't so easy to integrate with LaTeX (math labels and such)

Comment: @kissmyarmpit that link is very useful. The explanations are superb. Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use the [`tkz-berge`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-berge) package from Altermundus.

However, to make a simple example just using `TikZ`, you can follow this approach:

```
\documentclass {article}

% example taken from 
% http://www.guitex.org/home/images/doc/GuideGuIT/introingtikz.pdf

\usepackage {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
%\usepackage {xcolor}
\definecolor {processblue}{cmyk}{0.96,0,0,0}
\begin {document}
\begin {center}
\begin {tikzpicture}[-latex ,auto ,node distance =4 cm and 5cm ,on grid ,
semithick ,
state/.style ={ circle ,top color =white , bottom color = processblue!20 ,
draw,processblue , text=blue , minimum width =1 cm}]
\node[state] (C)
{$1$};
\node[state] (A) [above left=of C] {$0$};
\node[state] (B) [above right =of C] {$2$};
\path (A) edge [loop left] node[left] {$1/4$} (A);
\path (C) edge [bend left =25] node[below =0.15 cm] {$1/2$} (A);
\path (A) edge [bend right = -15] node[below =0.15 cm] {$1/2$} (C);
\path (A) edge [bend left =25] node[above] {$1/4$} (B);
\path (B) edge [bend left =15] node[below =0.15 cm] {$1/2$} (A);
\path (C) edge [bend left =15] node[below =0.15 cm] {$1/2$} (B);
\path (B) edge [bend right = -25] node[below =0.15 cm] {$1/2$} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which leads to:

[image]

It is an example of a Markov Chain in which several `TikZ` options are used. In the same guide, you will find an example in which nodes are placed in a matrix.

Comment: I remove some blank spaces before style and after the color because the code doesn't compile (problem with cut/past ?) . You don't need to load xcolor because tikz loads it but if you need some extra options of xcolor, you need to load xcolor before tikz. If you use `edge` instead of `to`, you can remove some extra commands example \path (A) edge ... (A) edge ... (B) edge ... (C) ; gives three edges that start from (A)

Comment: Thanks: great explanation. :) The problem of compilation was exactly due to cut and paste from the guide: I later removed several blank spaces, but probably I forgot someone.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino By any chance, do you know if there is an English language variant of the guide pointed to by: http://www.guitex.org/home/images/doc/GuideGuIT/introingtikz.pdf

Comment: @Ziezi: sorry, I never translated it and I'm not aware of any tranlations.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Never mind, it looks great and provides practical examples from many fields of Physics, it would have been great if I knew Italian, and understood the rest of the text.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino How can you adjust the bents more specifically if you want to use multi edges?

Comment: @Master.AKA: you should try a combination of bends and or the definition of in and out angles (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209303/13304)

Answer (score 30):

You can use the tkz-berge package . This package uses TikZ it's possible to add all the commands of TikZ.

Here the three classic forms of Petersen's graph

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}


\begin{document}
￼\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5] 
\GraphInit[vstyle=Art] 
\SetGraphArtColor{red}{olive} 
\grPetersen[form=1,RA=5,RB=3]%
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
   \GraphInit[vstyle=Art] 
   \SetGraphArtColor{red}{olive} 
   \grPetersen[form=2,RA=7,RB=3]%
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
   \GraphInit[vstyle=Art] 
   \SetGraphArtColor{red}{olive} 
   \grPetersen[form=3,RA=7]%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wrote a document with some classic named graphs. It's inside the your distribution (>2011 I think)

`texdoc NamedGraphs`in the terminal

I added the sources and all the examples you can also find them here

[NamedGraphs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-berge)

Answer (score 13):

Here an example to draw the Petersen's graph only with TikZ
I try to structure correctly the code. The first scope is used for vertices ans the second one for edges. The only problem is to get the edges with `mod``

```
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextb}{mod(\i+1,5)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nexta}{mod(\i+2,5)}
```

The complete code

```
  \documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{scope} [vertex style/.style={draw,
                                       circle,
                                       minimum size=6mm,
                                       inner sep=0pt,
                                       outer sep=0pt,
                                       shade}] 
      \path \foreach \i in {0,...,4}{%
       (72*\i:2) coordinate[vertex style] (a\i)
       (72*\i:4) coordinate[vertex style] (b\i)}
       ; 
    \end{scope}

     \begin{scope} [edge style/.style={draw=gray,double=white}]
       \foreach \i  in {0,...,4}{%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextb}{mod(\i+1,5)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nexta}{mod(\i+2,5)} 
       \draw[edge style] (a\i)--(b\i);
       \draw[edge style] (a\i)--(a\nexta);
       \draw[edge style] (b\i)--(b\nextb);
       }  
     \end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As there lacks an answer with pstricks, here a very simple code for the Petersen graph; it uses `pst-poly`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, pdf, x11names]{standalone}%

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-poly}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-1.1,-1)(1.1,1.1)
\providecommand{\PstPolygonNode}{%
\psdots[dotstyle=o, dotsize=3pt,fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=cyan](1;\INode)}
\psset{linewidth=0.6pt}
\rput(0,0){\PstPentagon[PolyName=A]}
\rput(0,0){\PstPentagon[unit=5mm, PolyOffset=2,PolyName=B]}
\multido{\i=1+1}{5}{\ncline[nodesep=1.5pt]{A\i}{B\i}}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not want to do the layout yourself, you can use Graphviz to do so.
That will result in a ".dot" file, that can be converted to Latex with dot2tex.

I just used my GraphvizFiddle tool to get "circo" layout for Petersen graph and verified that dot2tex works. Here is [share link](https://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/2.1.2/?1578940125795#graph%20petersen_graph%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20layout%3Dcirco%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Dpoint%5D%0A%20%20%20%201%20--%20%7B2%20--%20%7B3%20--%20%7B4%20--%205%7D%7D%7D%7D%20%0A%7D%0A) for the Petersen graph, switch output from "svg" to "dot" and press "Draw" button to get the Petersen ".dot" file. The tex output uses "tikzpicture" as well.

[image]