# is there a package to draw graphical models?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I would like to draw a few graphical models in latex. Is there a package that does that well?

I found the following package:

http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~dietz/probabilistic-models-tikz.zip

but the .tex file does not compile for me, it gives me errors such as:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: The function `add' already exists.

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.23 }

?
```

I was also hoping for something in which I can draw more "fancy" graphical models (perhaps with shading of the variables or the plates). If this package worked though, it would be a good start.

Comment: I think you can start by having a look to [How to draw graphs in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57152/how-to-draw-graphs-in-latex). With those hints as reference, you can build something similar to the link you provided.

Comment: Many `Underfull \vbox` warnings but no error here (with TeXLive 2012).

Comment: MikTeX 2.9 also works fine but scrbook complains about the old and obsolete options. They should be replaced by `mpinclude=false,  index=totoc,version=first, listof=totoc, cleardoublepage=current`. I would say the code is almost old and the TikZ code is not the best of its kind. However you should still need to update your TikZ package as it is most probably the case for the compile error.

Comment: First you need to use pgf 2.1 and perhaps you can try pgf 2.1 cvs if you want to use `\usepackage{pgfmath}` and not tikz.