# How to plot a discontinuous function curve and diagram of Markov chain with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

Please apologize my ingnorance of tips to use for asking questions.
I would like to realise the plots and the diagram like those shown on page 158,

[image]

160 
[image]

and 161
[image]

on this document [Chaine de Markov](http://epfl.wikispaces.com/file/view/MDS_MOD7_0607.pdf).

Any answers are welcome.

Comment: It would be good if you posted an image figure you are referring to, rather than posting a link to some other document. Exactly which part of those figures are you having difficulty with? Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: To draw the Markov chain you can have a look to the answers of [How to draw graphs in Latex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57152/13304).

Comment: Could you consider to accept one or the other answer? You've been member for more than two years asking 15 questions and accepted only one answer even though some of them sound technically corrected and appears to be very useful.

Answer (score 9):

My solutions adopts a command `\samplepath` able to create a sample path with the following syntax:

```
\samplepath{+|0.5,+|0.25,-|1.5,+|1,+|0.5,+|0.75}
```

where

- `+/-` represent the vertical changes of the path;
- numbers represent the time duration of the samples.

Similarly, there is another command `\discretesamplepath` which uses the same syntax, but it represents samples in discrete time.

There are actually two methods available:

- the first one uses the package [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) with the syntax described above;
- the second method does not use that package and replaces the delimiter `|` with `/`.

The code with [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring):

```
\documentclass[png,border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  vertical factor/.initial=0.5,
  vertical factor/.get=\vertfactor,
  vertical factor/.store in=\vertfactor,
  start coordinate/.initial={0,\vertfactor},
  start coordinate/.get=\startcoord,
  start coordinate/.store in=\startcoord,
  sample color/.initial=black,
  sample color/.get=\samplecol,
  sample color/.store in=\samplecol,
  sample size/.initial=1pt,
  sample size/.get=\samplesize,
  sample size/.store in=\samplesize,
  sample line width/.initial=very thick,
  sample line width/.get=\samplelinewidth,
  sample line width/.store in=\samplelinewidth,
}


\newcommand{\samplepath}[1]{%
\coordinate (start) at (\startcoord) ;
  \foreach \samples[count=\xi from 1] in {#1}{%     
     \StrCut{\samples}{|}{\vertdir}{\hordir}
     \ifnum\xi=1
       \draw[\samplelinewidth,\samplecol](start)
        --++(\hordir,0) coordinate (start);
     \else   
       \IfStrEq{\vertdir}{+}{%true
         \draw[\samplelinewidth,\samplecol]($(start)+(0,\vertfactor)$)
          --++(\hordir,0)coordinate(start);
       }{%false
         \relax
       }
       \IfStrEq{\vertdir}{-}{%true
         \draw[\samplelinewidth,\samplecol]($(start)+(0,-\vertfactor)$)
          --++(\hordir,0)coordinate(start);
       }{%false
         \relax
       }
     \fi
  }
}

\tikzset{sample/.style={    
    circle,
    inner sep=\samplesize,
    fill=\samplecol,
  }
}

\newcommand{\discretesamplepath}[1]{%
\coordinate (start) at (\startcoord) ;
  \foreach \samples[count=\xi from 1] in {#1}{%     
     \StrCut{\samples}{|}{\vertdir}{\hordir}
     \ifnum\xi=1
       \path(start)node[sample]{}
        --++(\hordir,0) coordinate (start);
     \else   
       \IfStrEq{\vertdir}{+}{%true
         \path($(start)+(0,\vertfactor)$)node[sample]{}
          --++(\hordir,0)coordinate(start);
       }{%false
         \relax
       }
       \IfStrEq{\vertdir}{-}{%true
         \path($(start)+(0,-\vertfactor)$)node[sample]{}
          --++(\hordir,0)coordinate(start);
       }{%false
         \relax
       }
     \fi
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% axis
\draw[-stealth] (0,-1)--(0,4) node[left]{$X(t)$};
\draw[-stealth] (-1,0)--(5,0) node[below]{$t$};
\samplepath{+|0.5,+|0.25,-|1.5,+|1,+|0.5,+|0.75}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code without [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\up{+}
\def\down{-}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  vertical factor/.initial=0.5,
  vertical factor/.get=\vertfactor,
  vertical factor/.store in=\vertfactor,
  start coordinate/.initial={0,\vertfactor},
  start coordinate/.get=\startcoord,
  start coordinate/.store in=\startcoord,
  sample color/.initial=black,
  sample color/.get=\samplecol,
  sample color/.store in=\samplecol,
  sample size/.initial=1pt,
  sample size/.get=\samplesize,
  sample size/.store in=\samplesize,
  sample line width/.initial=very thick,
  sample line width/.get=\samplelinewidth,
  sample line width/.store in=\samplelinewidth,
}


\newcommand{\samplepath}[1]{%
\coordinate (start) at (\startcoord) ;
  \foreach \vertdir/\hordir[count=\xi from 1] in {#1}{%
     \ifnum\xi=1
       \draw[\samplelinewidth,\samplecol](start)
        --++(\hordir,0) coordinate (start);
     \else   
       \ifx\vertdir\up%true
         \draw[\samplelinewidth,\samplecol]($(start)+(0,\vertfactor)$)
          --++(\hordir,0)coordinate(start);
       \else
         \relax
       \fi
       \ifx\vertdir\down%true
         \draw[\samplelinewidth,\samplecol]($(start)+(0,-\vertfactor)$)
          --++(\hordir,0)coordinate(start);
       \else
         \relax
       \fi
     \fi
  }
}

\tikzset{sample/.style={    
    circle,
    inner sep=\samplesize,
    fill=\samplecol,
  }
}

\newcommand{\discretesamplepath}[1]{%
\coordinate (start) at (\startcoord) ;
  \foreach \vertdir/\hordir[count=\xi from 1] in {#1}{%
     \ifnum\xi=1
       \path(start)node[sample]{}
        --++(\hordir,0) coordinate (start);
     \else   
       \ifx\vertdir\up%true
         \path($(start)+(0,\vertfactor)$)node[sample]{}
          --++(\hordir,0)coordinate(start);
       \else
         \relax
       \fi
       \ifx\vertdir\down%true
         \path($(start)+(0,-\vertfactor)$)node[sample]{}
          --++(\hordir,0)coordinate(start);
       \relax
         \relax
       \fi
     \fi
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% axis
\draw[-stealth] (0,-1)--(0,4) node[left]{$X(t)$};
\draw[-stealth] (-1,0)--(5,0) node[below]{$t$};
\samplepath{+/0.5,+/0.25,-/1.5,+/1,+/0.5,+/0.75}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result for both cases:

[image]

Some keys have been defined in order to customize the aspect: it is possible to use them via `\tikzset` or as option of the `tikzpicture`. In the following examples some of them will be used. Please, notice that these examples are with the method exploiting [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring).

First example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[start coordinate={0,0},font=\footnotesize]
\begin{scope}
% axis
\draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(4.5,0) node[below]{$t$};
\node at (0,1) {$X(t)$};
\samplepath{+|0.5,+|0.25,-|1,+|0.15,-|1.5,+|0.3,-|0.75}
\node at (4.5,1) {$0<\lambda \ll \mu$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
% axis
\draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(4.5,0) node[below]{$t$};
\node at (0,1) {$X(t)$};
\samplepath{+|0.55,+|0.75,-|0.65,+|1.5,-|1}
\node at (4.5,1) {$0<\lambda = \mu$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]
% axis
\draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(4.5,0) node[below]{$t$};
\node at (0,1) {$X(t)$};
\samplepath{+|0.2,+|0.4,-|0.15,+|0.4,-|0.3,+|0.2,
 -|0.2,+|0.2,-|0.4,+|0.2,-|0.3,+|0.5,-|0.2,+|0.4,-|0.4}
\node at (4.5,1) {$0\ll \lambda = \mu$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image]

Second example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{scope}[start coordinate={0,0}]
% axis
\draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(4.5,0) node[above]{$t$};
\node at (0,2) {$X(t)$};
\samplepath{+|0.5,+|1,+|0.75,-|0.5,-|0.25,+|0.35,+|0.4,+|0.55}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm,start coordinate={0.25,0},sample color=blue,sample size=1.25pt]
% axis
\draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(4.5,0) node[above]{$n$};
\node at (0,2) {$\hat{X}(n)$};
\discretesamplepath{+|0.5,+|1,+|0.75,-|0.5,-|0.25,+|0.35,+|0.4,+|0.55}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another piece of the puzzle:

[image: Brokenline]

Which was produced by the macro `\brokenline` I wrote. This macro draws one of those graphs, and takes four arguments. The first one is the vertical distance among the "steps" of the graph. The second one is a comma delimited list of the lengths of each segment. The third and fourth are the labels to appear at the left and right of the graph.

This is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\brokenline#1#2#3#4{
\coordinate (prev) at (0,0);
\foreach \x [count=\i] in {#2} {
 \draw[very thick] (prev) -- +(\x, 0) coordinate (cur);
 \ifodd\i\def\gap{#1}\else\def\gap{-#1}\fi
 \coordinate (prev) at ($(cur)+(0,\gap)$);
 }
 \draw[thin] (0,0) -- (prev|-0,0) node[right] (t) {$t$};
 \draw[very thick,->] (prev|-0,0)  +(-1pt,0) -- +(1pt,0);
 \draw (0,#1) node[above] {#3}
    (t|-0,#1) node[above left, inner xsep=0pt] {#4};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>= stealth, xscale=1.5]
\brokenline{0.5}{0.5, 0.3, 1, 0.2, 2, 0.4, 1.6}
{$X(t)$}{$0<\lambda\ll\mu$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vskip5mm

\begin{tikzpicture}[>= stealth, xscale=1.5]
\brokenline{0.5}{0.5, 1.2, 0.8, 2, 1.5}
{$X(t)$}{$0<\lambda=\mu$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vskip5mm

\begin{tikzpicture}[>= stealth, xscale=1.5]
\brokenline{0.5}{0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.25, 0.2, 0.45, 0.2, 0.25, 0.45, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.85}
{$X(t)$}{$0\ll\lambda=\mu$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please  http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino I can't run the first scipt.

Comment: there is the error code:

Comment: runsystem(latex -jobname 'Chainede*Markov1' '\expandafter \def \csname sa@inter
nal@run\endcsname {1}\input {Chainede*Markov1}')...quotation error in system co
mmand.

runsystem(dvips Chainede*Markov1.dvi)...disabled (restricted).

runsystem(gswin32c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r300 -sOutputFile
=Chainede*Markov1-%d.png Chainede*Markov1.ps)...disabled (restricted).

Comment: I apologizehttp://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12571/jldiaz  and thank you for your help. Notify you that I am on Windows 7 and I use Miketex with WinEdt. I have changed the file name in vain.

Comment: Would you allow me to open another file for this question.

Comment: @Averroès Yes, of course, you are welcome to ask as many question as neccesary!