# Drawing generic cumulative distributions

Tags: tikz-pgf

It might be trivially easy to learn but this is a bit urgent for me. So if anyone has some sample codes in latex to share with or document easily explain how to obtain something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Discrete_probability_distribution_illustration.svg it would be great. Many thanks!

Comment: Some references: [How to Draw CDF of normal distribution in Tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60950/13304), [How to plot a discontinuous function curve and diagram of Markov chain with TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104498/13304), [Modifying `*` and `o` style tikz arrows so that they are centered at the end of line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11871/13304), [What is the clearest way to graph a piecewise function?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63024/13304).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the urgency, there is a fast draft, without explanations. Feel free to ask.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  open/.style = {circle, minimum size=2mm,draw, fill=white,inner sep=0pt},
  closed/.style = {circle, minimum size=2mm, fill, inner sep=0pt},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[blue] (0,0) --  +(4,0) node[pos=0,left] {\tt\color{black} 1};
\draw[blue] (0,-1) -- +(4,0) node[pos=0,left] {\tt\color{black} 0};
\draw[red] (0,-1) -- (.6,-1) node[open] {};
\draw[red] (.6,-.75) node[closed] {} -- (1.6,-.75) node[open] {};
\draw[red] (1.6,-.4) node[closed] {} -- (3,-.4) node[open] {};
\draw[red] (3,0) node[closed] {} -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[blue] (0,0) --  +(4,0) node[pos=0,left] {\tt\color{black} 1};
\draw[blue] (0,-1) -- +(4,0) node[pos=0,left] {\tt\color{black} 0};
\draw[red] (0,-1) -- (1,-1) to[out=0,in=180] (3,0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[blue] (0,0) --  +(4,0) node[pos=0,left] {\tt\color{black} 1};
\draw[blue] (0,-1) -- +(4,0) node[pos=0,left] {\tt\color{black} 0};
\draw[red] (0,-1) -- (.3,-1) to[out=0, in=190] (1,-.9) node[open] {};
\draw[red] (1, -.6) node[closed] {} to[out=10,in=180] (3,0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]