# How to draw graphs on LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, diagrams

Sorry as this is a rather soft question, but I'm really struggling to get to grips with some packages for this (espcially since I really don't care about learning all the in's and out's). I literally just want the Petersen graph, $C_3$ and $C_6$. The problem with finding the pictures online is that the graphs will look inconsistent (different sizes of nodes etc from different webpages).

Comment: [Welcome to the side](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). You can use both [PSTricks](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-base) and [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for this.

Comment: @user55929: I've just added on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57152/how-to-draw-graphs-in-latex a way that uses pstricks (all other solutions use `tikz`.