# Labeled Petersen graph with new tikz graph library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

Following up on [Petersen graph with new tikz graph library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207953/petersen-graph-with-new-tikz-graph-library), I tried to label the vertices with something different than numbers. I thought the following would work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,circle,very thick}]
  \graph [clockwise,math nodes] {
    subgraph C_n [V={a,b,c,d,e},name=A, radius=2cm]; 
    subgraph I_n [V={f,g,h,i,j},name=B, radius=1cm];
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\j=int(mod(\i+1,5)+1);}] in {1,...,5}{
      A \i -- B \i;
      B \i -- B \j;
    }
  }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but it produces the following output. How could I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Replace `a,b,c,d,e` by `1,2,3,4,5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that by using `V={a,b,c,d,e}` the names as well as the labels of the nodes are changed. This will be a problem for arbitrary labels where I think the only workaround is to specify the edges manually without `\foreach`. However for alphabetic labels, one way of getting around this is to exploit an internal `pgf` command and define a math function to convert integers to letters:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{alpha}{1}{%
  \pgfmathint@{#1}%
  \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgffor@alpha{\pgfmathresult}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,circle,very thick}]
  \graph [clockwise,math nodes] {
    subgraph C_n [V={a,b,c,d,e},name=A, radius=2cm]; 
    subgraph I_n [V={f,g,h,i,j},name=B, radius=1cm];
    \foreach \x [evaluate={%
        \i=alpha(\x);
        \j=alpha(mod(\x+1,5)+6); 
        \k=alpha(\x+5);}] in {1,...,5}{
      A \i -- B \k;
      B \j -- B \k;
    }
  }; 
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative would be to define a "graph macro" which can be used in a graph in the same way as `subgraph C_n`. The following may not be the best way of doing things, but at least it appears to work:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\newcount\nodecount
\tikzgraphsset{
  declare={subgraph N}%
  {
    [/utils/exec={\global\nodecount=0}]
    \foreach \nodetext in \tikzgraphV
    {  [/utils/exec={\global\advance\nodecount by1}, 
      parse/.expand once={\the\nodecount/\nodetext}] }
  },
  declare={subgraph C}%
  {
    [cycle, /utils/exec={\global\nodecount=0}]
    \foreach \nodetext in \tikzgraphV
    {  [/utils/exec={\global\advance\nodecount by1}, 
      parse/.expand once={\the\nodecount/\nodetext}] }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,circle,very thick}]
  \graph [clockwise,math nodes] {     
    subgraph C [V={ {1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {1,5} }, name=A, radius=3cm]; 
    subgraph N [V={ {2,1}, {2,2}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {2,5} }, name=B, radius=1.5cm];
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\j=int(mod(\i+1,5)+1);}] in {1,...,5}{
      A \i -- B \i;  
      B \i -- B \j;
    }
  }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As a matter of fact, I really wanted to label the vertices with sets of 2 digits, as in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/269471/78149, and I thought I could adapt whatever answer I could get. But since it looks to be so complicated with the new tikz library, I will get back to tkz-graph and tkz-berge for this.

Comment: @rvf0068 I've updated the answer with a marginally better way of doing things using what the manual calls "graph macros" (See 19.8 Graph Macros) in the latest manual release. In principle you could define a "Peterson" graph macro.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question with a good answer, but it nagged at me that there wasn't a simpler way to draw the graph. So I experimented and found a simpler solution.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\tikzgraphsset{edges={draw,semithick}, nodes={circle,draw,semithick}}

\begin{document}

% I find slightly more space between layers more pleasing, hence
% the extra "radius=1.25cm" for the outer layer of nodes.
\tikz \graph[math nodes, clockwise]
    { subgraph I_n [V={f,g,h,i,j}] --
      subgraph C_n [V={a,b,c,d,e},radius=1.25cm];
      {[cycle] f,h,j,g,i} };

\end{document}
```

[image: Petersen graph]