# Something is wrong with tikz graphdrawing

Tags: luatex, tikz-trees, tikz-graphs

I wanted to see some isomorphisms of the Petersen graph; I took the code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207953/petersen-graph-with-new-tikz-graph-library), and run with several layouts from [here](https://tikz.dev/gd-usage-tikz), but the result with **tree layout** is not isomorphic to the Petersen graph:

```
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered}
\usegdlibrary{force,circular,trees}

\begin{document}

\tikz \graph[tree layout, nodes={empty nodes, draw, circle, inner sep=0.45mm, fill=black}, clockwise]
    { subgraph I_n [V={0,1,2,3,4}] --
      subgraph C_n [V={5,6,7,8,9},radius=1.25cm];
      {[cycle] 0,2,4,1,3} };
\end{document}
```

[image: In this graph built as a Petersen graph there are two points with only two edges]

Comment: If I'm searching the Internet for the phrase *Petersen graph* I'll see things that do not look like anything I'd classify as a `tree layout`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Right!  Thank you! The Petersen graph cannot be planar. The output of the code of a Petersen Graph with "tree layout" is not a Petersen Graph, but it is a Petersen Graph with other layouts. As I wrote in the comment to the answer, probably I failed to understand what layout means here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) is considered a graph with a `tree layout`.

If I remove `tree layout` from your `\graph` command I get a very different output.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph[
  nodes={empty nodes, draw, fill, circle, inner sep=0.45mm},
  clockwise
] {
  subgraph I_n [V={0,1,2,3,4}]
  --
  subgraph C_n [V={5,6,7,8,9}, radius=1.25cm];
  {[cycle] 0,2,4,1,3};
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My purpose was to find isomorphic graphs to that of Petersen. And my assumption was that changing the layout don't affect the structure of the graph. So, when I ran the code, I thought that either (a) I do not quite understand what a layout is, or (b) There is something wrong in the "tree layout" of tikz-graph. I was inclined to answer (b), because all the other layouts resulted in isomorphic graphs. But by your answer, now I am more inclined to think that (a) is the correct assumption.