# TikZ in/out angle vs. Bezier controls

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the figure below, I would like both segments to have the upward arrow that's currently in the left-hand segment, but I would also like both segments to have the nice round shape that's currently in the right-hand segment.

[image]

MWE code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{smallnode}=[circle, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, minimum size=2mm, draw=black, fill=black];

    \node[smallnode, label={$i$}] (i)   at (0,0) {};
    \node[smallnode, label=below:{$j$}] (j)     at (1.5,-1) {};
    \node[smallnode, label={$k$}] (k)       at (1.5,0) {};
    \node[smallnode, label=below:{$l$}] (l)     at (0,-1) {};

    \draw (i) to[out=180, in=180, edge node={node [sloped,below] {$\leftarrow$}}] (l);
    \draw (k) .. controls ($ (k) +(2,1)$) and ($ (j) +(2,-1)$) .. (j);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that using out/in angles, as in the left segment, doesn't allow flexibility in how "rounded" the curve appears, though it does make it very easy to add the arrow. On the other hand, using Bezier curves, as in the left segment, doesn't seem to allow edge nodes (or does it? -- I tried

```
\draw (k) to[out=180, in=180, edge node={node [sloped,below] {$\leftarrow$}}] 
          .. controls ($ (k) +(2,1)$) and ($ (j) +(2,-1)$) .. (j);
```

and a few other syntaxes but couldn't get it).

By the way, I'm a pretty new TikZ user, so if I'm doing anything else silly in this code, please let me know!

Comment: You can start reading a bit about the `tension` key if my memory serves me well.

Comment: Also `looseness`.

Comment: Thanks. `tension` seems to apply only to plots. But `looseness` did the trick. @Manuel, please post as an answer; I'll accept it and post my final code.

Comment: I didn't even read the question (and I think I don't know the answer), answer it yourself, or wait for someone else.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My final code, based on @Manuel's suggestion:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{smallnode}=[circle, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, minimum size=2mm, draw=black, fill=black];

    \node[smallnode, label={$i$}] (i)   at (0,0) {};
    \node[smallnode, label=below:{$j$}] (j)     at (1.5,-1) {};
    \node[smallnode, label={$k$}] (k)       at (1.5,0) {};
    \node[smallnode, label=below:{$l$}] (l)     at (0,-1) {};

    \draw (i) to[out=150, in=210, looseness=4, edge node={node [sloped,below] {$\leftarrow$}}] (l);
    \draw (k) to[out=30, in=-30, looseness=4, edge node={node [sloped,above] {$\leftarrow$}}] (j);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can always place a node over the path and attach some label to it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{smallnode}=[circle, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, minimum size=2mm, draw=black, fill=black];

    \node[smallnode, label={$i$}] (i)   at (0,0) {};
    \node[smallnode, label=below:{$j$}] (j)     at (1.5,-1) {};
    \node[smallnode, label={$k$}] (k)       at (1.5,0) {};
    \node[smallnode, label=below:{$l$}] (l)     at (0,-1) {};

    \draw (i) to[out=180, in=180, edge node={node [sloped,below] {$\leftarrow$}}] (l);
    \draw (k) .. controls ($ (k) +(2,1)$) and ($ (j) +(2,-1)$) .. (j) node[pos=0.5, inner sep=-1pt, label=right:{$\uparrow$}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- this is a good trick too, but I think `looseness` is a simpler way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Metapost version for comparison.  I've defined the two curves as `path` variables, so that I can then use the `point x of y` notation to place a label at a suitable point along the path.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

u = 1/2cm;
z1 = -z2 = (-3/2u,+u);
z3 = -z4 = (+3/2u,+u);

path h[];
h1 = z2 {dir -30} .. {dir 210} z3;
h2 = z4 {dir 210} .. {dir -30} z1;

draw h1; 
draw h2; 

label.rt (btex $\uparrow$ etex, point 0.5 of h1);
label.lft(btex $\uparrow$ etex, point 0.5 of h2);

dotlabel.top(btex $i$ etex, z1);
dotlabel.bot(btex $j$ etex, z2);
dotlabel.top(btex $k$ etex, z3);
dotlabel.bot(btex $l$ etex, z4);

endfig;
end.
```

However you can make rather sexier arrows by using `subpath` to draw an arbitrary part of the part shifted sideways a bit, like this:

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(2);
u = 1/2cm;

z1 = -z2 = (-3/2u,+u);
z3 = -z4 = (+3/2u,+u);

path h[];
h1 = z2 {dir -30} .. {dir 210} z3;
h2 = z4 {dir 210} .. {dir -30} z1;

draw h1; 
draw h2; 

drawarrow subpath (0.4,0.6) of h1 shifted 5 right;
drawarrow subpath (0.4,0.6) of h2 shifted 5 left;

dotlabel.top(btex $i$ etex, z1);
dotlabel.bot(btex $j$ etex, z2);
dotlabel.top(btex $k$ etex, z3);
dotlabel.bot(btex $l$ etex, z4);

endfig;
end.
```

Comment: Ooh, I like the sexy arrows. I don't use MetaPost but will see whether I can find a way to convert this to TikZ.