# Right Branch of Function Call Graph missing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\definecolor {turboviole}{cmyk}{0.70,0,0,0}

\begin {document}
\begin {center}
\begin {tikzpicture}[-latex ,auto ,node distance =4 cm and 5cm ,on grid ,
semithick ,
state/.style ={ circle ,top color =white , bottom color = turboviole!20 ,
draw,turboviole , text=blue , minimum width =1 cm}]

% Left branch
\node[state] (root) {$[5,4,6,2,9,1,7,3]$};
\node[state] (A) [below left=of root] {$[4,1,2,3]$};
\node[state] (B) [below left=of A] {$[2,1,3]$};
\node[state] (C) [below left=of B] {$[1]$};
\node[state] (D) [below right=of B] {$[3]$};

% Call paths
\path (root) edge [bend right =25] node [below left=0.15cm] 
{$\textcolor{red}{Call 1},Pivot < 5$} (A);
\path (A) edge [bend right =25] node [below left =0.15 cm] {$\textcolor{red}
{Call 2}, Pivot <4$} (B);
\path (B) edge [bend right =25] node [below left =0.15 cm] {$\textcolor{red}
{Call 3}, Pivot <2$} (C);
\path (B) edge [bend left =25] node [below right=0.15 cm] {$\textcolor{red}
{Call 4}, Pivot >2$} (D);

% Returning paths
\path (C) edge [bend right =25] node [above right =0.15 cm {$\textcolor{green}{Return 1}$} (B);
\path (D) edge [bend left =25] node [above left =0.15 cm] {$\textcolor{green}{Return 2}$} (B);
\path (B) edge [bend right =25] node [above right =0.15 cm] {$\textcolor{green}{Return 3}$} (A);
\path (A) edge [bend right =25] node [above right =0.15 cm] {$\textcolor{green}{Return 4}$} (root);

% Right branch
\node[state] (E) [below right=of root] {$[6,9,7]$};
\node[state] (F) [below right=of E] {$[9,7]$};
\node[state] (G) [below right=of F] {$[7]$};

% Call Paths
\path (root) edge [bend left =25] node [below right=0.15cm] {$\textcolor{red}{Call 5}, Pivot > 5$} (E);
\path (E) edge [bend left =25] node [below right=0.15 cm] {$\textcolor{red}{Call 6}, Pivot >6$} (F);
\path (F) edge [bend left =25] node [below right=0.15 cm] {$\textcolor{red}{Call 7}, Pivot >9$} (G);

% Returning paths
% intentionally not included

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

I would like your suggestions and recommendations regarding:

- the missing right part of the graph. What am I doing wrong?
- changing the colour of the `edges` to match text colour the in *description nodes*<sup>The ones containing:
  Call and Return.</sup>. How to change colour of the edges?
- how to place the text of the *description nodes* above the edges, so that it is visible?

Any additional constructive comment will be also appreciated!

---

Note: idea for the code borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57152/how-to-draw-graphs-in-latex).

Comment: The right part isn't really missing, your diagram is just so large that it extends outside the page. Try changing the `node distance` to for example `node distance=3cm and 1.2cm`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank your for the comment, you are right, but the whole graph is, for some reason, also shifted to the right.

Comment: `1cm` then, instead of `1.2cm`. It was a little bit wider than the text block (note the overfull hbox warning in the log, or add `\usepackage{showframe}` to see it) with 1.2cm, so it went into the right margin a bit.

Comment: Add e.g. `fill=white` to the nodes you want 'above' the edges.  Add e.g. `[draw=blue]` so you have `edge [draw=blue]` rather than just `edge` to add colour, or `\draw [blue]` if it is not an edge in Ti*k*Z's sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: the right part isn't missing, it's just that your diagram is very wide, so you see the same as if you inserted an image that was 25cm wide -- it sticks into the right margin and out of the page. An easy fix is to set `node distance=3cm and 1cm`, instead of the `4cm and 5cm` you have.

In the code below I made several manual adjustments to this though, to make better use of the space.

Regarding the colors, you could use `edge[draw=red]` to make an edge red, as cfr remarks in a comment. Alternatively, as you're adding both arrow and node in the same `path`, you could do `\path [red] ...`. I do a variation of this below, where I use a `scope` environment and `every path/.append style={}`. Making the entire node red, of course means that `Pivot N > 5` will be red as well, that can be fixed with a `\color{black}`.

There are other changes to the code as well, ask if anything is unclear.

(Note: the frame in the image is from the `showframe` package, and is merely there to show that the diagram is narrower than the text width. You'll want to remove the `showframe` package.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{turboviole}{cmyk}{0.70,0,0,0}
\newcommand\callpivot[2]{Call #1,\\\color{black}$\text{Pivot #2} > 5$}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   -latex,
   auto,
   node distance=3cm and 1cm,
   on grid,
   semithick,
   state/.style={
     circle,
     top color=white,
     bottom color=turboviole!20,
     draw,
     turboviole,
     text=blue,
     minimum width=1cm
   },
   call/.style={
     red,
     every node/.append style={align=center}
   },
   return/.style={green}
]

% Left branch
\node[state] (root) {$[5,4,6,2,9,1,7,3]$};
\node[state] (A) [below left=2cm and 3cm of root] {$[4,1,2,3]$};
\node[state] (B) [below left=3cm and 0cm of A] {$[2,1,3]$};
\node[state] (C) [below left=3cm and 2cm of B] {$[1]$};
\node[state] (D) [below right=3and 2cm of B] {$[3]$};

% Call paths
\begin{scope}[every path/.append style={call}]
\path (root) edge [bend right=25] node [above left]  {\callpivot{1}{5}} (A);
\path (A) edge [bend right=25] node [left] {\callpivot{2}{4}} (B);
\path (B) edge [bend right=25] node [above left] {\callpivot{3}{2}} (C);
\path (B) edge [bend left=25] node [above right] {\callpivot{4},{2}} (D);
\end{scope}

% Returning paths
\begin{scope}[every path/.append style={return}]
\path (C) edge [bend right=15] node [right,pos=0.1] {Return 1} (B);
\path (D) edge [bend left=15] node [left,pos=0.4] {Return 2} (B);
\path (B) edge [bend right=25] node [right] {Return 3} (A);
\path (A) edge [bend right=25] node [below right] {Return 4} (root);
\end{scope}

% Right branch
\node[state] (E) [below right=2cm and 3cm of root] {$[6,9,7]$};
\node[state] (F) [below=of E] {$[9,7]$};
\node[state] (G) [below=of F] {$[7]$};

% Call Paths
\begin{scope}[every path/.append style={call}]
\path (root) edge [bend left=25] node [above right] {\callpivot{5}{5}} (E);
\path (E) edge [bend left=25] node [right] {\callpivot{6}{6}} (F);
\path (F) edge [bend left=25] node [right] {\callpivot{7}{9}} (G);
\end{scope}

% Returning paths
% intentionally not included

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```