# Destination of arrows in Tikz overlapping

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm]
\node[state] (moderate) {moderate};
\node[state, minimum size=2cm] (above) [below right of=moderate, xshift=1cm, yshift=-3cm] {above};
\node[state, minimum size=2cm, xshift=-1cm, yshift=-3cm] (below) [below left of=moderate] {below};
\path[->] (moderate) edge [loop above] node {\texttt{t\_high = 0, t\_low = 0}} (moderate)
    edge [bend left] node {\texttt{t\_high = 1}} (above)
    edge [bend left] node[align=center, xshift=-2cm, yshift=1cm] {\texttt{t\_low = 1}} (below)
    (above) edge [loop right] node {\texttt{t\_high = 1}} (above)
            edge [bend right] node {\texttt{t\_low = 1}} (below)
            edge [bend left] node[align=center, xshift=2.2cm, yshift=1cm] {\texttt{t\_high = 0,}\\\texttt{t\_low = 0}} (moderate)
    (below) edge [loop left] node {\texttt{t\_low = 1}} (below)
            edge [bend left] node[align=center] {\texttt{t\_high = 0,}\\\texttt{t\_low = 0}} (moderate)
            edge [bend right] node {\texttt{t\_high = 1}} (above);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: State machine diagram]
I'm trying to draw a state machine diagram with Tikz. However, the destinations of the arrows seem to be overlapping at the same point of the nodes. I would like them to space out evenly so that one can easily tell different arrows apart; how can I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. Is there a way to get these arcs flatter? They seem to be really "fat".

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57925. It explains how you can set the bend angle.

Comment: @StefanH Thanks for the tip - any idea about the arrow issue?

Comment: @StefanH I mean, changing the bend angle does make the problem go away, but I'd still like to know if there's a way to fix it manually.

Comment: @ZhangEdison, what do you mean by manually?

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli I mean is it possible to force the ends of the arrows to be "evenly" distributed around the circle instead of cram together?

Comment: @ZhangEdison, well, they're cramming together because of the current `bend angle` (which is the default 30) and the whole symmetry of the drawing itself. If you want you can use `edge[in=angle, out=angle]` Syntax and manually specify the in and out angles... Although usually the automated solution is preffered

Comment: The nodes form a 60-60-60 triangle. Saying `bend right` by default means starting and ending 30 degrees to the right of the straight line. That is why you get them crammed together. Set `bend angle=20` should set them evenly around the circle.

Comment: You can also combine `(below.12)edge(above.34)`.