# Referencing a Vertex that has Math Typesetting inside it to make an Edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-external, pgfmath

I want to create math font inside of my vertex circles, AND draw edges between them. How I typically create network graphs is as follows:

```
\usepackage{tkz-graph}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[x=1,y=6]{A};
\Vertex[x=1,y=5]{B}
\Vertex[x=1,y=4]{C}
\Edge[label= 20](B)(C)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, if I do the following, it doesn't work. How can I get around this so that I can have equations or math font inside my nodes and connect them with an edge?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[x=1,y=6]{$\frac{x}{y}$};
\Vertex[x=1,y=5]{$2^n$}
\Vertex[x=1,y=4]{$t$}
\Edge[label= 20]($2^n$)($t$)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The letters in the first examples serve as node labels hence referencing them needs text chars/numbers. If you want to put other types of labels you need to use `L=<special chars>` options. If `L=` option is empty the node label automatically becomes the visual label.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\show\Vertex
\Vertex[L=$\frac{x}{y}$,x=1,y=6]{A};
\Vertex[L=$2^n$,x=1,y=5]{B}
\Vertex[L=$t$,x=1,y=4]{T}
\Edge[label= 20](B)(T)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also see the manual page 21 for `[Math]` option and `\SetVertexMath` switch.