# How do you make a tkz graph with edges starting and ending at the same vertex?

Tags: graphs, tkz-graph

I am trying to use the tkz-graph package to put together a directed graph. I have never used it before, so I am trying to piece together examples I have found on the internet. Below is the code that I have so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\SetUpEdge[lw = 1.5pt, color = blue]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Normal] 
\SetGraphUnit{4}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.append  style={fill}}
\Vertex{S}
\EA(S){I} \EA(I){R}
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}}
\Edge[label=$\beta$](I)(R)
\Edge[label=$\alpha$](S)(I)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives me a graph with three vertices, and two edges. I want to also add in a loop, starting and ending at the same vertex, for each vertex. I tried including the following three lines:

```
\Edge[label=$1-\alpha$](S)(S)
\Edge[label=$1-\beta$](I)(I)
\Edge[label=$1$](R)(R)
```

But this didn't work. The graph just came out looking messy. I also tried to fiddling with the angle of the edges, by doing the following:

```
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}, in=45, out=135}
\Edge[label=$1-\alpha$](S)(S)
\Edge[label=$1-\beta$](I)(I)
\Edge[label=$1$](R)(R)
```

But it still looked messy. I just want those edges to look like loops, with labels on them, as shown in the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It will always attract more help if you post an MWE, such that potential commentators don't have to invent prembles etc.

Comment: I'd really like to help you, but the whole documentation for `tkz-graph` is in french. Does anybody know, if there is an english version?

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't think [Alain](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/alain-matthes) has written an English manual, but there are plenty of examples in the manual, so you can learn something from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `\Loop` command for this, see the example on page 25 of [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tkz-graph).

The syntax is

```
\Loop[<options>](<vertex>)
```

without any spaces before/after brackets/parens.

In the options one can specify

- `dir` - the possible values are `WE`, `EA`, `NO`, `SO`, `NOWE`, `NOEA`, `SOWE`, `SOEA` for west, east, north, south, north west etc., e.g. `dir=NO`.
- `dist` - defines the size of the loop. Specify a length, e.g. `dist=2cm`.
- `label` - the label of the vertex, e.g. `label={$a$}`
- `style` - the style of the loop, allowing you to customize thickness, color etc., e.g. `style={green,->,thick}`
- `labelstyle` - the style of the label, allowing you to customize positioning, colour etc., e.g. `labelstyle={above}` to place the label above the loop.

### Example

[image: result of code below]

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\SetUpEdge[lw = 1.5pt, color = blue]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Normal] 
\SetGraphUnit{4}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.append  style={fill}}
\Vertex{S}
\EA(S){I} \EA(I){R}
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}}
\Edge[label=$\beta$](I)(R)
\Edge[label=$\alpha$](S)(I)
\Loop[dir=NO,label={$1-\beta$},labelstyle={above}](I)
\Loop[dir=SO,dist=1cm](R)
\Loop[dir=WE,dist=2cm,style={blue,very thick},label={$1-\alpha$},labelstyle={fill=white}](S)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```