# Self-loops in graphs change their shapes when the picture is rotated

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

I am using `tkz-graph` for drawing graphs.  Self-loops change their shapes when the picture is rotated.  Is this normal?  Since I could probably redesign the rotated graph from the beginning, I am more interested in knowing why the behaviour occurs, or whether I am doing something wrong than in solving the problem.  An example follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\newcommand{\tp}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=#1]
                         \Vertex{a}
                         \Loop(a)
                    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}     
     \tp{0}

     \tp{90}

     \tp{180}

     \tp{270}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the angles are just the one on your example we can also go to other solutions and use `\Loop`. But I think the code can not remain so simple as yours.

Comment: I edited my answer and think that it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
 in it's source it has:

```
\let\loop\grLoop
```

And grLoop is defined as:

```
\newcommand*{\grLoop}[1][]{\tkzGR@loop[#1]}%
\def\tkzGR@loop[#1](#2){%
\setkeys[GR]{loop}{#1}%
\protected@edef\@tempa{%
\noexpand \draw[\cmdGR@loop@color] (#2)%
  edge [EdgeStyle,LoopStyle,\cmdGR@loop@style]%
  node [LabelStyle,\cmdGR@loop@labelstyle]%
  {\cmdGR@loop@label} (#2)}\@tempa;%
}%
```

So we have to check `EdgeStyle,LoopStyle,\cmdGR@loop@style`

But in initializing Loopstyle contains:

```
\define@choicekey*[GR]{loop}{dir}[\val\nr]{WE,EA,NO,SO,NOWE,NOEA,SOWE,SOEA}{%
\ifcase\nr\relax
\tikzset{LoopStyle/.style = {in=225, out=135, distance=\cmdGR@loop@dist}}%
\or
\tikzset{LoopStyle/.style = {in= 45, out=-45, distance=\cmdGR@loop@dist}}%
\or
\tikzset{LoopStyle/.style = {in=135, out= 45, distance=\cmdGR@loop@dist}}%
\or
\tikzset{LoopStyle/.style = {in=-45, out=-135, distance=\cmdGR@loop@dist}}%
\or
\tikzset{LoopStyle/.style = {in=180, out=90, distance=\cmdGR@loop@dist}}%
\or
\tikzset{LoopStyle/.style = {in=90, out=0, distance=\cmdGR@loop@dist}}%
\or
\tikzset{LoopStyle/.style = {in=-90, out=-180, distance=\cmdGR@loop@dist}}%
\or
\tikzset{LoopStyle/.style = {in=0, out=-90, distance=\cmdGR@loop@dist}}%
\fi%
}
```

And that means that the starting point  does not initializing there (just angles and distance)

So looking for the other option I find that `\cmdGR@loop@style` is
no refered anywhere else and that probably is empty.

So the package doesn't provides any option for real rotation.

And if I try a loop with the code:

```
\newcommand{\tp}[1]{\xdef\ea{#1+90}\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=#1]
                         \Vertex{a}
                         \draw (a) edge [in=0, out=90,distance=40] (a);
                    \end{tikzpicture}}
```

I get the same problem. This problem is reproduced by `\Loop` command

If I could add to `in` or if latex was adding to it by the rotation it would
by better. May be we have to fill a bug for no valid rotation of edge options.

**Old Answer:**

What about something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\newcommand{\tp}[1]{\xdef\val{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro\vval{#1+60}\begin{tikzpicture}
                         \Vertex{a}
                         \path[->] (a) edge [out=\val,in=\vval,looseness=9] (a);
                    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}     
     \tp{0}

     \tp{90}

     \tp{180}

     \tp{270}
\end{document}
```

I just found here: [How do you make a tkz graph with edges starting and ending at the same vertex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127299/how-do-you-make-a-tkz-graph-with-edges-starting-and-ending-at-the-same-vertex) that `\Loop` command takes strange arguments for direction (see `dir` option) and may be this breaks the behavior. We can also do other thinks using calculations if this is not problem for you. But I think you can see now what is the problem.

Comment: Thank you.  However, I am more interested in knowing why the behaviour occurs, or whether I am doing something wrong than in solving the problem.  Sorry for not being clear from the start.

Comment: Yes. This is my last sentence. (Because I got that in my mind by your question)...[So:Off comment (for anyone interested): For better solution than this I gave I could define a macro giving back the strings NW NE etc]. Welcome

Comment: I thought I had explain that you have to mention the starting point of the `Loop`... It remains the same point at all the Loops... and this is what breaks the image's appearance.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.  But, why the starting point does not rotate together with the rest of the picture?  The actual behaviour is not what I would have expected.