# Invisible vertices with tkz-graph

Tags: tkz-graph

Is it possible to hide the vertices while using package `tkz-graph`?  Firstly I want to show just the edges, and then show the whole graph.  However, I need the vertices from the beginning in order to draw the edges between them.  I tried with `MinSize=0pt` without success.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
    Without vertices (fail; vertices are still visible):
    \SetVertexSimple[MinSize=0pt] 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Vertex{A}
        \Vertex[x=4,y=0]{B}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=2]{C}
        \Edge[style={bend left}](B)(A)
        \Edges(A,B,C,A)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    With vertices:
    \SetVertexSimple[MinSize=10pt]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Vertex{A}
        \Vertex[x=4,y=0]{B}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=2]{C}
        \Edge[style={bend left}](B)(A)
        \Edges(A,B,C,A)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: @Harish:  Sample added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can use `VertexStyle/.style={shape=coordinate}` to make the vertices coordinates, so the edges will touch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
    \SetVertexSimple[MinSize=10pt]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Vertex{A}
        \Vertex[x=4,y=0]{B}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=2]{C}
        \Edge[style={bend left}](B)(A)
        \Edges(A,B,C,A)
    \end{tikzpicture}\qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}[VertexStyle/.style={shape=coordinate}]
        \Vertex{A}
        \Vertex[x=4,y=0]{B}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=2]{C}
        \Edge[style={bend left}](B)(A)
        \Edges(A,B,C,A)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option would be to use the `empty` key for *all* vertices:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\presetkeys[GR]{vertex}{empty=true}{}
         \Vertex{A}
         \Vertex[,x=4,y=0]{B}
         \Vertex[,x=1,y=2]{C}
         \Edge[style={bend left}](B)(A)
         \Edges(A,B,C,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
         \Vertex{A}
         \Vertex[,x=4,y=0]{B}
         \Vertex[,x=1,y=2]{C}
         \Edge[style={bend left}](B)(A)
         \Edges(A,B,C,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using beamer.  Besides, I do not want the holes when the vertices are invisible.  Edges should touch.

Comment: @ASdeL So, are we supposed to guess what you are using and what do you want? Please add to your question all relevant information and a minimal example with your current settings.

Comment: @ASdeL Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Local option `empty` can be used in a node by node basis (although tiny holes are shown).

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tkz-graph}
 \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \Vertex[empty]{A}
         \Vertex[empty,x=4,y=0]{B}
         \Vertex[empty,x=1,y=2]{C}
         \Edge[style={bend left}](B)(A)
         \Edges(A,B,C,A)
     \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

I wonder whether is it possible to specify `empty` just once.

Comment: To answer your question, please see my updated answer.