# Problem with tikz and rotating labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels, rotating

I am fairly new to LaTeX and especially to tikz. I tried to draw a directed graph which actually turned out the way I wanted it to. I don't know how well written this code is, but it works. Code in question:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,->,line width=1pt, domain=0:2,label/.style={%
   postaction={ decorate,transform shape,
   decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.5 with \node #1;}}}]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,
column sep={1.5cm,between origins},
row sep={2.2cm,between origins},
nodes={circle, draw, minimum size=1cm}] {
& |(1)| J &   & |(2)| A & \\
&  & |(3)| R &  \\};
\draw[label={[below]{$50$}}] (2)--(1);
\draw[label={[below]{$25 \%$}}] (3)--(2);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=2pt, yshift=2pt}, shorten <= -1pt, label=    {[below]{$100$}}] (3)--(1);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=-2pt, yshift=-2pt}, shorten <= -1pt, label=    {[below]{$2 \%$}}] (1)--(3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, after discovering a working solution to add labels to the lines drawn, I now have the problems that the topmost label is upside down. Why this is so, is clear to me, however I don't know how to fix it.

I have read something about doing stuff like

```
\draw[label={[below, rotate=180]{$50$}}] (2)--(1);
```

but it's not working.

If you happen to know how to solve my problem or improve the structure of the directed graph, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Does the answer at [Typesetting a directed, weighted graph with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37185/) help at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your picture remind me on automaton, so why don't use `automata` library?

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,positioning,babel}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance = 30mm,
     on grid,
     auto,
                 > = {Stealth[length=5pt,width=4pt]},
every state/.style = {draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20}
                        ]
\node[state] (J) {$J$};
\node[state] (R) [below right=of J] {$R$};
\node[state] (A) [above right=of R] {$A$};
\path[->]   (A) edge            node[above]          {50}    (J)
            (J) edge[bend left] node[pos=0.4,sloped] {2\%}   (R)
            (R) edge            node[pos=0.7,sloped] {25\%}  (A)
            (R) edge[bend left] node[pos=0.4,sloped] {100}   (J)
            ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

Since `sloped` option of edge nodes doesn't put edge labels on the middle of the pat, I manually correct their position (by trial).

**Upgrade:** by use of library `quotes` the draw this automation is even simpler:

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,quotes,positioning,babel}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance = 30mm,
     on grid,
                 > = {Stealth[length=5pt,width=4pt]},
every state/.style = {very thick},
every edge quotes/.style = {sloped, anchor=north}
                        ]
\node[state] (J) {$J$};
\node[state] (R) [below right=of J] {$R$};
\node[state] (A) [above right=of R] {$A$};
\path[->]   (A) edge ["50"]             (J)
            (J) edge[bend left,"2\%"]   (R)
            (R) edge["25\%"]            (A)
            (R) edge[bend left,"100"]   (J);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Obtained picture is almost the same (this time in "black and white" version). And here is not necessary manual adjusting of edge labels ...

**Edit:**
I was not aware with possible implication of used babel on the provided code. One solution, how to copy with this provide OP:

```
\usepackage[shorthands=off,ngerman]{babel}
```

Another, more general -- as remind me Gonzalo Medina -- is use babel library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,quotes,positioning,%
                babel% for avoid complications with any language in babel
                }
```

I correct both above examples accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ever so much. This is a nice version, however it does not seem to work for me. I always get syntax errors about missing brackets (}), if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Meh, I figured that out. Somehow the babel  [ngerman] library conflicts with your code. I don't know why. When I removed it, the code worked.

Comment: Apparently the babel ngerman library makes _"_ an active character. This is why the code failed at _"50"_. I am now figuring out, how to get it working.

Comment: It's working now. I was mistaken in my first comment, there were no brackets missing but babel interpreting " as an active character to do shorthands like `"a`. With `\usepackage[shorthands=off,ngerman]{babel}` I was able to disable the shorthands, because I don't need them, and now everything works fine.

Comment: Some babels change active characters. I usual use English in for my native languages, where is no such problems. I'm not expert for babels, but I'm pretty sure, that somewhere in SE is solution for this (I remember that I saw for similar cases solution for Spanish and French babels).

Comment: I'm glad that you find solution for babel. I will store it in my private examples collection. Happy TeXing!

Comment: @Zarko `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` (from PGF version 3.0 and later) should fix those problems with active characters.

Answer (score 3):

You won't need a `label` style but add the nodes staright away.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,->,line width=1pt]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,
column sep={1.5cm,between origins},
row sep={2.2cm,between origins},
nodes={circle, draw, minimum size=1cm}] {
& |(1)| J &   & |(2)| A & \\
&  & |(3)| R &  \\};
\draw(2)-- node[below]{$50$}(1);
\draw (3)--node[below,sloped]{$25\%$}(2);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=2pt, yshift=2pt}, shorten <= -1pt,] (3)-- node[rotate=180,below,sloped]{$100$}(1);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=-2pt, yshift=-2pt}, shorten <= -1pt] (1)-- node[below,sloped]{$2\%$}(3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can insert the node after the second point as well as before it.  Tikz knows where midway is either way.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: That way one has to explicitly use `midway` or `pos=0.5`.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Just curiosity. How do you postprocess your results to get images like this one? Your images are always cropped and framed, but posted code doesn't use `standalone` nor command for frames.

Comment: @Ignasi: I am on windows and there is this snipping tool (I think from vista onwards). I take a screen shot and in settings of snipping tool keep the border on.